# How to require a file in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have two files named sample and dbConnect in which have methods in a class.I need to call those methods in sample.I tried by requiring dbConnect file in sample.
My code is `require 'filename'`. But it throws error.
Where I am going wrong ? I am learning ruby starter so this may be a silly question.Please help me.

**UPDATE :**

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require  'dbConnect.rb'
```

It says,

```
sample.rb:4:in `require': ./lib/clsDataEngine.rb:3: class/module name must be CONSTANT (SyntaxError)
from sample.rb:4
```

I tried by giving full path like this

```
require '/home/kshanmugharaj/Projects/ruby/lib/clsDataEngine.rb'
```

For that it says,

```
require': /home/kshanmugharaj/Projects/ruby/lib/clsDataEngine.rb:3: class/module name must be CONSTANT (SyntaxError)
```

My requirement is i have two files in a same folder. I need to call methods which is in dbConnect from sample.

What should i do ?
Please help me out..

**Working :-** I wrote class name as wrong. I made it DBConnect with UpperCase as starting letter and it works.

Comment: check your **/lib/clsDataEngine.rb:3**. In both of your errors messages they tells you that your class/module is not constant(not starting with big letter). This is good name: `class Mamamam; end` this is bad: `class mamamam; end`. Same goes for module, good: `module M; end` bad: `module m`;

Comment: Yup.. Too silly. Its working man.Thanks Darek nedza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

You need this because your files are not in the load path. Otherwise you can provide full o relative path to your ruby files like:

```
require '/home/foo/filename'
```

or

```
require './filename'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should show the error you get on your issue.

Try with:

```
require_relative 'path_to_file_you_want'
```

Do not use extension .rb, only file name.

Example:

You have a file called sample.rb and a class file called dbConnect.rb on /lib
on sample.rb you can use:

```
require_relative 'lib/dbConnect'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can require ruby module different way, Below is the one example.

```
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__)

require 'csv_exp/version'

// base,client,util are sub folders inside csv_exp(folder) gem 
command_files = "../csv_exp/{base,client,util}/*.rb"
Dir[File.expand_path(command_files, __FILE__)].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

I hope, this help you.

Answer (score 0):

The file must be in `lib` folder along the path stored in the `$:` global variable. So make sure that your library is along the path. Simple way is to use [`bundler`](http://bundler.io/#getting-started). It will expand your lib path `$:` to one, in which all gem libraries is includes already. All gems you should specify in the [Gemfile](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html).

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'your_db_driver_gem'
```

**ruby_script.rb**

```
require 'your_db_driver_lib'
```

And workaround method is to specify fullpath to the library:

```
require '/full/path/to/the/library/filename'
```